# How to fill an ArrayList from a file and format the output.

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, formatting

I am working on this project here for school and I really am stuck at this point. Basically I have to take a text file. Then I have to fill an arraylist(s) with the information inside it. After that I need to format it correctly so that I can use it for Category, question, and answer. I have no idea how to do that, so below is what the instructor asks us if that helps clear it up any further.

> "In this assignment you will write an application that simulates a
> trivia game. You will be given a text file that contains a set of
> questions and answers in six different categories. Your program will
> select a random question from each category to be answered by the
> player. The score will be displayed at the end of each run.
>
> Input data format: The input file contains questions and answers in
> different categories. For each category, the first line indicates the
> name of the category. This line will be followed by a number of pairs
> of lines. The first line of the pair is the question, and the second
> line is its corresponding answer. A blank line separates the
> categories. Technical requirements:
>
>  Create a class called TriviaQuestion that represents a typical question object.
>
>  After reading the data, store the information inside ArrayList(s).
>
>  Be user friendly in your input/output. Ignore cases. Accept partially correct answers if possible."

Right now as my code will show I am stuck on how to add the info to the ArrayList in the format that he has specified. I don't want anyone to do my work for me. I just need nudged in the proper direction. I dont know if I need many arraylists for each category and if I do, do I need them to be in seperate classes? This is only my second semester so I'm still pretty perplexed by these things. There are other jave trivia games online and on this forum but I can't find any that work in this fashion. Anyway, here is the code and the text file afterwards....

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class TriviaGame {

/**
 * I want to make several array lists and then use a random question for each         category. Then compare the user
 * answer to the real answer to see if they won. Keep a count of the correct answers. Ignore case. 
 */
//instance fields
private String player; // The player
private int points;        // Player's number of points
private String currentAnswer; // Current typed answer
private File gameFile = new File ("trivia.txt");


//constructors

public TriviaGame(String playerName)
{
    playerName = player;
    points = 0;
}


public TriviaGame(String player, int points, String currentAnswer,
        File gameFile, ArrayList<String> triviaQuestion) {
    super();
    this.player = player;
    this.points = points;
    this.currentAnswer = currentAnswer;
    this.gameFile = gameFile;
    }


//Getters and Setters
/**
 * @return the player
 */
public String getPlayer() {
    return player;
}


/**
 * @param player the player to set
 */
public void setPlayer(String player) {
    this.player = player;
}


/**
 * @return the points
 */
public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}


/**
 * @param points the points to set
 */
public void setPoints(int points) {
    this.points = points;
}


/**
 * @return the currentAnswer
 */
public String getCurrentAnswer() {
    return currentAnswer;
}


/**
 * @param currentAnswer the currentAnswer to set
 */
public void setCurrentAnswer(String currentAnswer) {
    this.currentAnswer = currentAnswer;
}


/**
 * @return the gameFile
 */
public File getGameFile() {
    return gameFile;
}


/**
 * @param gameFile the gameFile to set
 */
public void setGameFile(File gameFile) {
    this.gameFile = gameFile;
}


//To String Method

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TriviaGame [player=" + player + ", points=" + points
            + ", currentAnswer=" + currentAnswer + ", gameFile=" +     gameFile
            + ", getClass()=" + getClass() + ", hashCode()=" + hashCode()
            + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
}




}
```

followed by the tester.....

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class TriviaGamePlayer {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    File gameFile = new File ("trivia.txt");
    ArrayList<String> triviaQuestion = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(gameFile);
    String line;
    

    while(infile.hasNext()){
        line = infile.nextLine();
        triviaQuestion = line.split();

}

}


}
```

finally the some of the text file that accompanied it.....

```
Arts & Literature
What are bongo drums traditionally held between for playing?
The knees
The Hugo Awards are given for the best literature in which genre?
Science fiction
What four-letter girl's name gave Jane Austen the title of a comic novel?
Emma
Andy Warhol was born in what US city?
Pittsburgh
Who wrote the novel "The Chocolate War"?
Robert Cormier
What surname for John in "The Importance of Being Earnest" did Oscar Wilde take from the seaside town he vacationed at?
Worthing

Geography
What is the modern day equivalent of Dacia?
Romania
What is the capital of Ontario?
Toronto
Which island boasts of being Napoleon's birthplace?
Corsica
What nationality is a Breton?
French
A person from North Carolina is properly known as a what?
North Carolinian
In which country would you find St. Basil's cathedral?
Russia
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an ArrayList or TriviaQuestion objects

```
List<TriviaQuestion> triviaQuestions = new ArrayList<TriviaQuestion>();
```

Create a TriviaQuestion class in the most simple form like this

```
public class TriviaQuestion {
  String category;
  String question;
  String answer;
}
```

You can populate it like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File gameFile = new File("trivia.txt");
    List<TriviaQuestion> triviaQuestions = new ArrayList<TriviaQuestion>();
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(gameFile);
    String lastKnownCategory = "";

    while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
        String currentLine = infile.nextLine();

        if (!currentLine.isEmpty()) {
            TriviaQuestion currentQuestion = new TriviaQuestion();

            if (currentLine.endsWith("?")) {
                currentQuestion.category = lastKnownCategory;
                currentQuestion.question = currentLine;
                currentQuestion.answer = infile.nextLine();
            } else {
                currentQuestion.category = currentLine;
                currentQuestion.question = infile.nextLine();
                currentQuestion.answer = infile.nextLine();
                lastKnownCategory = currentLine;
            }
            triviaQuestions.add(currentQuestion);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, just so I understand what you are doing here, the first line of code is making an arraylist correct? But the part that is being passed is the object TriviaQuestion from the class correct?

Comment: That is a generic. It tells the compiler that you are creating an ArrayList which will contain a list of Objects of type TriviaQuestion.

Comment: So which argument do I pass to System.out.print so that I can ask the user to answer one of those questions at random?

Comment: You have a collection of questions. That collection has an index. You should write code that finds out the size of your collection and than generate a random number no larger than the size of the collection. Take that random number and use it to pull out the random TriviaQuestion object that lives in at the random index of the collection and display the question.

Comment: Sort of like this:  System.out.println(triviaQuestions.size());
     
     System.out.println((int)Math.random() * (triviaQuestions.size())); That would give me the size but i know my code for the random is a bit off. Now i just have to figure out how to extract the quesiton from the index and make sure its one question per category